# How to generate a vector x in R such that its outer product is positive definite?

Tags: r, math, matrix

```
set.seed(3)
n <- 5  
x <- rnorm(n)

# Compute x x^T
xxT <- outer(x, x)

library(matrixcalc)
> is.positive.definite(xxT)
[1] FALSE
```

The above approach does not guarantee that xx^T is positive definite. What's a workaround?

Comment: AFAIK, `xxT` created by this way won't be positive definite, because its rank will always be 1, meaning not a full rank matrix. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3164224/328688. `xxT` will be positive semidefinite, but when not full rank, it will not be positive definite.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463835/why-is-rmvnorm-function-returning-in-sqrtevvalues-nans-produced-what-i/22464988#22464988. And. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859899/cant-get-a-positive-definite-variance-matrix-when-very-small-eigen-values/16860957#16860957

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long story short: You have ***no way*** to make `xxT` positive definite.

---

Mathematically, if length of `x` is greater than `1`, then `xxT` is positive semi-definite rather than positive definite, since you can always find the null space of any given vector `x`. That means, you can always find a nonzero matrix `A` whose null space contains `x`, such that `t(v) %*% xxT %*% v` -> `(t(v)%*%x) %*% t(t(v) %*% x)` -> `0 %*% t(0)` -> `0`, where `0` is a all-zero vector.

With `x` in your example, you can see the null of `x` can be obtained by

```
> (nulls <- MASS::Null(x))
            [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]
[1,] -0.18713251  0.16555019 -0.73703375  0.12524482
[2,]  0.97832152  0.01917826 -0.08538212  0.01450906
[3,]  0.01917826  0.98303360  0.07553485 -0.01283571
[4,] -0.08538212  0.07553485  0.66371688  0.05714490
[5,]  0.01450906 -0.01283571  0.05714490  0.99028931
```

and verify `nulls` by

```
> crossprod(nulls, x)
              [,1]
[1,] -4.640385e-17
[2,] -3.729655e-17
[3,]  9.887924e-17
[4,]  5.551115e-17
```

In this sense, any vector `v` from the space spanned by `nulls` will lead to `t(v) %*% xxT %*% v == 0`, thus not positive definite but positive semi-definite.

Comment: A couple of nitpicks: (1) `tcrossprod(x)` is (trivially) positive definite when `length(x)` is 1 and `x` is nonzero.  (2) You say, "you can always find a nonzero vector `v` in the null space of `x`", but I think you mean, "you can always find a nonzero matrix `A` whose null space contains `x` ... ?  Then any nonzero row of that matrix will work as your `v` ...

Comment: @MikaelJagan Thanks for making rigorous descriptions. Updated in the answer.